# Perl Mechanize, submitting a form with a file (image)?

Tags: perl, mechanize, form-submit

I can't seem to find a good example of how to do this properly, the ones I have found aren't working for me.. I am trying to submit a form using perl mechanize, where the form has an image file, the form is as below, its actually a way I am trying to access this API for a website from which I have an account and using POST seems to be the easiest way to use their API:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<form 
 method="post" 
 name="image_upload"
 action="http://example-website.com" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="field1"  value="">
 <input type="text"   name="username"  value="">
 <input type="text"   name="password"  value="">
 <input type="file"   name="pict">
 <input type="text"   name="field2"   value="0">
 <input type="text"   name="field3" value="0">
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried this, but its not uploading the image file, it seems.. any advice is appreciated. (I left out parts of the script for simplicity, but I am able to submit other forms using this method, just not ones that require a file upload)

fill form field:

```
$mech->form_name('image_upload');

$mech->set_fields( field1 => '', 
username => $username,
password => $password,
pict => '/home/user1/Desktop/pic.jpg',
field2 => '0',
field3 => '0'
);

#### submit form
$mech->submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging, add `autocheck => 1` to the `$mech` object, it will print the error and return on the earliest unsuccessful call.

Also, add a  `print $mech->content` after the call to `$mech->submit`,

You may be getting some error page, in which case you can try setting user agent:

`$mech->agent_alias( 'Windows IE 6' )`

Or, maybe you need to get a cookie from an earlier page in order to upload. (you can test this by clearing cookies in your browser and trying to upload straight from the upload page)

Comment: I don't need to debug it as I already know the unsuccessful call.. its the place where I am trying to upload the image.. its more about not being able to find the proper syntax for uploading an image in a form with mechanize than anything else

Comment: There's no special syntax for uploading an image. The code you pasted seems fine, could you elaborate on what 'unsuccessful' means? what happens after $mech->submit?